# EnableQuery(MaxTop = 20) Does not work

Tags: odata

I am using System.Web.OData, but When I apply EnableQuery(PageSize = 20, MaxTop = 20)  on controller action , it doesn't work. Still it return all the records.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: @LAM have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

The maxtop query Gets or sets the max value of $top that a client can request.
when using the query  `[EnableQuery(MaxTop = 20)]` it returns all the records, but sets the max value of $top client request. so if client access $top=x x more than max top value it shows the following error.

"code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '20' for Top query has been exceeded.

`(PageSize = 20)` Gets or sets the maximum number of query results to send back to clients. So if you are using the pagesize query, it returns the 20 records.